# I need a C wire connection for my new Glas thermostat

Tags: wiring, thermostat, furnace, thermostat-c-wire

I have 3 wires(red,white,and green) going to my thermostat. I’m replacing my old thermostat with a new one the requires a C wire connection. The 3 wires goes to my Honeywell aquastat. The white goes to TV, the red goes to T, and the green doesn’t go anywhere. But I do have a Z connector. Can I use the green wire as a C wire and connect to the Z? Any ideas

[image]

[image]

[image][image][image][image]

Comment: What model is your aquastat?

Comment: It’s a L8148G. Thank you for replying

Comment: I want to give you a full picture of what I want to do. I want to replace my old Honeywell thermostat with the new Glas thermostat. It requires a C wire. The new thermostat came with a C wire adapter. I post all the pictures to see. So now do I connect the Green wire to the Z connector on my Aquastat and make that the C wire? And the green wire going to my thermostat do I connect it in the C connector?

Answer (score 1):

### Connect the green wire to Z

While some boiler relay modules (aquastat relays) don't provide a C terminal at all, yours thankfully does; it's merely going incognito.  The label gives it away, though, as it states that your aquastat supports a maximum of 30VA of load between T<sub>V</sub> and Z.

Once you connect the green wire at the aquastat to its Z terminal, you can then connect your white wire to R, your red wire to W, and your green wire to C when wiring up the new thermostat, and all should be well.

Comment: All did go well, thank you so much. It worked perfectly.

Comment: @JeanMorisset -- we thank people around here by upvoting and/or accepting their answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the green wire is likely an "extra" unused wire that can be used as the C wire.

Comment: Do you have anything to back this up?

Comment: I want to give you a full picture of what I want to do. I want to replace my old Honeywell thermostat with the new Glas thermostat. It requires a C wire. The new thermostat came with a C wire adapter. I post all the pictures to see. So now do I connect the Green wire to the Z connector on my Aquastat and make that the C wire? And the green wire going to my thermostat do I connect it in the C connector? Thank you so much